# Getting list of files in a directory WITHOUT paths in Ruby

Tags: ruby

(I can't believe how long I've spent on this so I'm just gonna ask it...)

Given a directory path, how do I get the list of the file names underneath it *excluding the path prefix*. Yeah I could strip them off but I feel like I'm missing a cleaner way?

Specifically, I want all the files under the `/config` directory in Rails:

```
files = Dir[Rails.root.join("config").to_s + "/*"]
files = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("config").to_s + "/*")
```

Each of these returns full-path file names...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`Dir.entries`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries) !

```
Dir.entries(Rails.root.join("config").to_s)
```

Comment: @oldergod- A SCHOLAR AND A GENTLEMAN

Comment: Correct. It should, because those are legitimate entries in a directory. It's up to the OP to check for hidden and special files. Sometimes not all files in a directory can safely be read or written to.

Comment: this still gave me the full path